# Segmentation fault? String tokenization

Tags: c, c89

I'm trying to write a function will convert the characters from an array into ints so that I can produce a sum or other math process for each group. I know that first I have to use strtok to get rid of the spaces and '+'. I've been trying to first at least start with getting strtok to work but it keeps saying segmentation fault when I try to run it.

Any help?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char* string[] = { "10 + 20", "1 + 3 + 6 + 8" };
    sum(string[0]);
}

int sum(char* s)
{
    char *stringcopy = malloc( strlen(s) + 1 );     
    char* del = " +";                                  
    char* token;
    int i;

    stringcopy = s;   /* 'copy' problem here */             

    token = strtok(stringcopy, del);
    while( token ) {
       printf("%s\n", token);
       token = strtok(NULL, del);
    }
    return 11;   /* placeholder until I get the sum */
}
```

Comment: Tip: Use proper indentation and add he `C` tag. Anyway, are you sure it must be C89?

Comment: `textcopy = s;` - this doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes it must be in C89 format.

Comment: @Crisis: Ok, in that case better mention that you need that version, but still tag with the general language tag for a wider audience.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I figured it was too good to be true. What does it actually do? What should I do instead?

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple reason `strtok` gives you a segmentation fault:

You are running it on a string literal, which despite having type `char[n]` is an immutable object.
`strtok` modifies any string you run it on!

The work-around is simple: Run on a copy. Here a function for duplicating strings (most C libraries provide this non-standard function as `char* strdup(const char*)`:

```
char* my_strdup(const char* s) {
    size_t size = strlen(s)+1;
    char* ret = malloc(size);
    if(ret)
        memcpy(ret, s, size);
    return ret;
}
```

Don't forget to `free()` the copy later.

You tried doing so, but after getting off to a good start and reserving space for the string with `malloc`, you just discarded it (memory leak) by assigning a pointer to the literal to that same pointer.

Comment: You didn't make a copy. See my answer.

Comment: @Crisis: Yes, that's it.

Comment: What I like about this answer: the strdup function is a very good thing to know about. (I think most C runtime libraries provide one for you, though?)

Answer (score 1):

This line does not do what you thought it would:

```
textcopy = s;   /* making copy for strtok */
```

No string is copied here. All that happens is that instead of pointing to the first byte of the block of memory that you just allocated for it (with `malloc( strlen(s) + 1 )`),
`textcopy` now points directly at the first byte of the literal string `"10 + 20"` that you passed to `stringSum` as `s`.

You probably wanted something like `strcpy(textcopy, s)`. I had suggested `strncpy` earlier; `strncpy(textcopy, s, strlen(s)) + 1` might work, but (as the comments explain) seems to be rather pointless to use in this context.

Comment: He probably wanted `strcpy(textcopy, s);` . Your suggestion does not create a string.

Comment: Don't use `strncpy`, it is evil incarnate (unless you really know what you are doing). Anyway, you get the buffer length to pass wrong.

Comment: Ah, right, if you use `strncpy` better either add one to the length of the string or write a null to `textcopy(strlen(s))` afterward. And since he'd already made sure the buffer was big enough to hold `strlen(s) + 1`, the usual excuses for `strncpy` don't apply.

Comment: @Deduplicator was spot on about the buffer length; I've attempted to correct that now. I didn't remove the mention of `strncpy` (since comments refer to it), but made note of `strcpy`. And I probably would have suggested `strcpy` myself before Microsoft got all paranoid about it. Maybe I still should.

Comment: @DavidK: The trouble with `strncpy()` is that it is for a really specialized niche: Filling part of the beginning of a buffer with non-0 values from a provided string / long enough buffer, and filling the rest with 0s. If that is not what you want (like, just about never), it is either inefficient or flat-out wrong.

Comment: Honestly I'm wondering why I even mentioned `strncpy` in this particular case. In all the code I've ever written, `strncpy` practically always meant I wanted to extract a substring of something, so I was sure I would in fact get `n` non-zero values, and `strcpy` would copy too much because `s[n]` was not zero).

Comment: Actually think I know why I thought of `strncpy` -- it was all those "strcpy is unsafe" warnings Visual Studio started spewing at me. What I have to wonder is why I let them influence me here.

Answer (score 1):

This statement

```
textcopy = s;   /* making copy for strtok */
```

does not do what you think.

In fact there us a memory leak because at first you allocated memory and textcopy got the address of the first byte of the storage

```
char *textcopy = malloc( strlen(s) + 1 );
```

and then you reassigned textcopy.

```
textcopy = s;   /* making copy for strtok */
```

You have to use standard function `strcpy` instead

```
strcpy( textcopy, s );   /* making copy for strtok */
```

Also it would be better if the function would declared as

```
int stringSum(const char* s);
```

Comment: Using strcpy( textcopy, s); gives me an error saying 'too few arguments to function'

Comment: @Crisis First of all you need to include header <string.h>. The function has exactly two parameters so if the header is included the compiler can not issue such an error.

Comment: That's strange, because I do have that included in my header.

Comment: @Crisis Check maybe you wrote strncpy( textcopy, s ); instead of strcpy( textcopy, s );

Comment: I must've confused the other function posted here with that one. I don't get the error anymore, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
textcopy = s;   /* making copy for strtok */
```

doesn't make copy of `s` and put it in `textcopy`. Instead, you need to use:

```
strcpy(textcopy, s);
```